# Chrome extension: cannot create tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Just trying to create a simple tab and I cannot get it to work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
          "19": "logo_19.png"
      },
      "default_title": "Test Suite",
      "default_popup": "main.html"
   },  
   "description": "Test Suite Description",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon_128.png",
      "16": "icon_16.png"
   },   
   "name": "Test Suite",
   "permissions": ["http://www.google.com/"],
   "version": "1.0"
}
```

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu-items-ui">    
    <div id="registration">
     Google Search
      </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var registration = document.getElementById('registration');
    registration.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'http://www.google.com' });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

It is not going to the google site.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have html in your javascript file, remove it

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var registration = document.getElementById('registration');
    registration.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'http://www.google.com' });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: oops should have noticed it before asking!